# How to update java on macOS Sierra 10.12

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I am trying to install eclipse-cpp oxygen on macOS Sierra 10.12. While installing it i get an error that java version is not 1.8, while I had already installed latest JDK package. on terminal it shows java version as below

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```

Please suggest how can I upgrade my java version.

Comment: What's this latest JDK package that you installed? Where did it come from? What does `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` in a Terminal report?

Comment: above command reports asVandits-MacBook-Air:~ jain$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-468, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 2):

Apple don't provide a version of Java greater than Java 6. You must install Java 8 from the Oracle site.

In order to run Eclipse you must install the full JDK, the JRE download is not enough as it does not include the `java` executable.

The Oracle site is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Depends on what you need to do.  Eclipse does not need javac so for that the JDK is not needed.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No, on macOS installing just the JRE only installs the browser plugins. You only get an executable `java` command by installing the JDK - this is absolutely required on macOS.

Comment: That can't be right. The java command starts a Java VM, aka the Java run-time, and it's included in both the JRE (Java Run-time Env) and JDK (Java Dev Kit). The JDK includes also the developer tools, such as the compiler javac, Visual VM debugger, and much more.

Comment: @Paul No, that is not the case on macOS. The JRE install only installed the browser plugins, a JDK is required for the java command. This is different from other OSs for some reason known only to Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Java8 from here.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

make sure to check the latest binaries of java and javac in PATH. You can override the old java binaries in path.